# Missing windows authentication IIS component because of Windows Vista Home Premium edition... any fixes out there?

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-vista, version, windows-authentication

Apparently Windows Vista Home Basic and Premium both do not ship with integrated windows authentication for IIS (You need Business edition)... so does anyone know how to get windows authentication installed for IIS?

I went into ***Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off***. Then in the Windows Features popup I navigated to... ***Internet Information Serivces > World Wide Web Services > Security > ???***

Under security the only options that were there are:

- Basic Authentication
- IP Security
- Request Filtering
- URL Authorization

I found [this fix](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB937523) but it gave me this error message:

> The upgrade Patch cannot be installed by Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a **different version of the program**. Verify that the program exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch.

So that makes me think it's because the fix is for Visual Studio 2005, and I'm using Visual Studio 2008. Anyone know a fix that applies to Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can get it to work in Vista Home Premium because the Home editions do not support domain authentication; only workgroup authentication.  You have to get one of the Business editions or Ultimate.

Comment: With Windows 7, I believe the Professional version will include domain authentication; you won't have to go to Ultimate.

Comment: It came with my laptop, how it that my fault. HP should take windows out of the price of laptops and let us buy our own version rather than being stuck with the version it comes with.

Comment: Ouch just ran into this as well.. now I'm spending the whole day installing a new OS :(

Comment: Upvote and word of warning to all would-be Sharepoint customer/developers/testers: Don't try installing it on Windows 7 unless it's a business/premium version. You'll waste a lot of time and end up having a lot of stuff to remove. They really should point that out in the documentation (double checked and zero mention of particular version requirements). Ah well, I'm off to do a fresh install of Windows to get rid of all this rubbish, yay :(

Comment: For Windows 7, the Professional version will work as well as the Business versions. Plus, you can now do in place upgrades - enter the new Product Key and the new features are installed/enabled meaning no more reinstall to get the additional features.