# Windows authentication does not exist in IIS Features?

Tags: authentication, iis, iis-7, webserver

I do not know why, but I can not activate Windows Authentication for IIS and many other feature, as they are all missing in the security section for Programs "Windows Features".
As the photo below

I really hope someone would help me

I already try to unistall IIS and reinstall
I use Windows 7 O.S Professional
And IIS worked fine last week on my computer , but not now .. I don't know why :'(

[image]
[image]

Sorry on the picture it's all in french ^^ But almost same in english ;-)

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing windows authentication IIS component because of Windows Vista Home Premium edition... any fixes out there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207666/missing-windows-authentication-iis-component-because-of-windows-vista-home-premi)

Comment: I use Windows 7 Professional ! And for @Anders Abel -> this post is not a duplicate of Missing windows authentication IIS component because of Windows Vista ... My IIS worked fine before . And now no , but i don't know why :'(